Shell-init errors when starting the system with pivot_root
I am using sysvinit and I can start the system directly by these kernel options:
root=/dev/sda1 rootfstype=ext4 init=/sbin/init

And it works perfectly. But if I add a middle filesystem like with this:
(a simplified example)
root=/dev/sdb2 rootfstype=squashfs init=/myscript

Where /myscript is a BusyBox script like this:
#!/busybox sh
echo Welcome
mount /dev/sda1 /newroot
cd /newroot/mnt
pivot_root /newroot .
exec /sbin/init

Then it also starts up, but during the SysVInit boot after pivot_root and exec, I see many messages in console like this:
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory

What is the issue?

try cd / before exec /sbin/init?
